# ACE editor syntax check for ANTLR grammar rules

Tags: antlr4, ace-editor

Ace editor uses mode.js to highlight keywords and worker.js to check syntax. In ACE editor, I want to validate syntax for ANTLR grammar rules(from .g4 file) for given user input and highlight them. By default ACE can validate syntax for Javascript(JSHint), JSON etc.

> Similarly is it possible to do for ANTLR grammar ? And if so how to do it ?

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/ace-javascript-target.md